# Integral of 3 variables

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have to solve the following integral $$\int_{0}^{R} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-z^2}} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-y^2-z^2}}(x^2+y^2+z^2)dx dy dz$$

My idea is to use spherical coordinates, but I have difficulties to adjust the limits. Can you help me out?

Comment: Hint what is volume of a sphere?

Comment: I know this probably is half of the volume. But I don't know how to adjust the limits as a general rule. What do I have to do if I don't know what object the function describes?

Comment: this is not a descriptive enough title. any integral of 3 variables could be matched to ur title. Please provide the uniqueness to ur question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Move to spherical coordinates. We have
$$x^2+y^2+z^2 = r^2$$
and
$$dx dy dz = r^2 \sin(\theta) dr d\theta d\phi$$

Comment: Thanks, but I already knew this. I simply dont know how to adjust the limits. Since this looks a lot like half of a sphere, I suggest from$ 0$ to R, from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and from $0$ to $\pi $. Is this correct?

Comment: In your integral, your $x,y,z > 0$, which is the first octant. Hence, $\theta \in [0,\pi/2]$ and $\phi \in [0,\pi/2]$. Your $r$ goes from $0$ to $R$.

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$ V = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 : x,y,z\geq 0, x^2+y^2+z^2\leq R^2\}. $$
Then, by simmetry, your integral equals:
$$ I = \int_{V}(x^2+y^2+z^2)\,d\mu = 3\int_{V} x^2\,d\mu = 3\int_{0}^{R}x^2\frac{\pi}{4}(R^2-x^2)\,dx\\=\frac{3\pi}{4}R^5\int_{0}^{1}x^2(1-x^2)\,dx=\frac{3\pi}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{15}R^5=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{10}R^5}.$$

Comment: okay, I calculated it in a different way, but I get the same result. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

let $$\begin{align}&x = \rho \sin \phi \sin \theta\\&y = \rho \cos \phi \sin \theta\\&z = \rho \cos \phi\end{align}$$

Notice that $x^2+y^2+z^2 = R^2$ With $dV = \rho^2 \sin \phi d\rho\  d\phi\  d\theta$.

Also $$0 \leq \rho \leq R\\0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}\\0\leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: not by me. I upvoted :<

Comment: Do you understand?

Comment: Yeah, the only problem I have is to adjust the limits if I don't know what object the function describes. Here I know it is a sphere, but what do I do if I don't know this?

Comment: It's often good to skecth a drawing of the region so you may have an idea of the limits for $\rho, \theta$ and $\phi$. You need to know how to identify each.